# Is it OK to ask a question about what approach to take to show external data in Salesforce?

Tags: discussion, support

We need to show a lot of data related to accounts in Salesforce. Currently, the data is being presented in an external reporting system. However, users want to be to pull-up this data in Salesforce both via desktop and mobile.

I'm wanting to know if it is appropriate to ask what possible strategies could be used to present account level data in Salesforce. My concerns is the question could be seen as more opinion-based. However, I believe this is a challenged faced by many other Salesforce administrators and developers.

Is this question appropriate for Salesforce Stack Exchange?

Comment: I think it *can* be appropriate or off topic, and it entirely depends on how you ask. If you demonstrate what options you have researched, point out which pros and cons you have noted so far, and be clear about what drawbacks you can live with, you can write an on-topic question that gets you what you need in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might as well convert it to an answer:

I think it *can* be appropriate or off topic, and it entirely depends on how you ask. If you demonstrate what options you have researched, point out which pros and cons you have noted so far, and be clear about what drawbacks you can live with, you can write an on-topic question that gets you what you need in this regard.

It would also be easy to write an off-topic question which comes across as too broad or opinion based. That's why it's important to clarify the points I mention above.

Comment: Turns out my client is going a different path, but I'll keep your advice in mind if I end up posting this question. Thanks for your help!